# Memory management with Javascript static classes and methods

Tags: javascript, class, memory

I wanna know how these things works.

```
class Test {
    whatIsMyName(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    tellMyName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

let a = new Test();
a.whatIsMyName("Bob");
a.tellMyName(); // "Bob"
```

> Browser assigns a part of memory to variable `a`.
>   Browser keeps the memory until I refresh the website.

```
class Test {
    static whatIsMyName() {
        const name = "Bob";
        return name;
    }
    static tellMyName() {
        return Test.whatIsMyName();
    }
}

Test.whatIsMyName(); // "Bob"
Test.whatIsMyName(); // "Bob"
Test.tellMyName(); // "Bob"
```

> Does browser assign another part of memory when I call it more than one?

Answer (score 1):

> Does browser assign another part of memory when I call it more than one?

Very likely, yes². It has to allocate the string `"bob"`, and it creates a local variable `name`. Both consume memory. As you do neither create a closure or store the string somewhere, all references to it will be lost after every of these calls, thus garbage collection might free the memory directly afterwards.

<sub>² modern js engines do a lot of clever optimizations though, maybe they optimize things away ...</sub>

Comment: I learned how to test it. I create snaphost before calling any static method and after calling about 100 times static method in Test class. The memory (counts) of object is just increasing. Does Garbage collection do its work immediately?

Comment: It depends. The engines usually do have multiple garbage collectors: (1) The most optimal case is if a variable has a point of no return, then the engine will immeadiately collect it then, (2) there are a lot of "short living" objects in JS, there is a garbagge collector that keeps track of them and removes them, (3) there is a garbagge collector for long living objects.

Comment: The general rule of garbagge collection is: It doesn't make sense to spend a lot of time to free memory if the memory is not needed at all. Thereforeif you want to see the garbagge collector in action you have to *fill up the memory a lot*.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr Native implementations are wacky and situational, and almost always as efficient as can be imagined.  They don't do what you say, they do what you mean.

This can vary between JavaScript engines, but let's assume you're talking about the v8 engine or an extension of it.

Telling exactly what it does is difficult without looking at the source code, but I've run jsperf tests on string copies before and found that v8 appears to do as little copying of strings as possible.  You can call substr all you want and have no performance hit.  You can copy strings all over the place and it'll act like nothing happened.  But the moment you modify a string even a little, performance drops dramatically.

What I glean from this is that it does not copy a string to a new place in memory until you modify it.  Which is to say, all of these should access the same string in memory, with at most a start index and length differing:

```
const str = "string";
const str2 = str; // same memory
const str3 = str2; // same memory
const snip = str.slice(1,3); // different start position and length, same memory

const diff = str.replace("i", "o"); // potentially some shared memory, but performance drops would indicate a copy happens
```

If you really want to know exactly when things are copied vs when a reference is used, you'd have to look at the source code for v8 (https://github.com/v8/v8).

Further, how browsers actually implement the javascript can vary a lot depending on the situation.  For instance, it might copy in a case like this: `"hat".replace("a", "o")` because "hat" is short, but then chain string snippets together in a case like this `"Imagine a whole book here".replace("a phrase that happens once", "CENSORED")`.  It would definitely be most efficient to check the length of the modified string and amount of replacing, and either copy or chain snippets depending on those variables.

Comment: That's weird. I thought primitive values don't refer to memory. When you change `str` variable the others don't change. It means they don't refer and don't share the same memory, do they?

Comment: So JS acts like strings are pass by value.  But (asfaict) how it actually implements it on the inside is optimized.  That's kind of what makes JS a scripting language, and not a real language.  In JS, there's very clear definitions of what something should do in effect, but how it actually manages that is arbitrary.  Conversely, compiled languages do exactly as you say, exactly as you say it, even when it's a bad idea (minus some well documented optimizations).

Comment: Do they share the memory until any string is changed? After that, it assigns memory to new string. For example: `var a = "a"; var b = a; // same memory as **var a**; var b = "b" // now both variables have different memory` Am I right?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, but something performant appears to be happening when you run tests.  You'd have to look at the source code to know what.  I only cared enough to check it wasn't doing things the slow way.